# How to print number from list without using seperator

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

`print(*[1,2,3])` outputs as: `1 2 3`
`print(*[1,2,3],sep='')` outputs as: `123`, 
 which is string type.

Is there any way to `print` `[1,2,3]` as `integer` type `123`

Comment: `print(int(''.join(map(str, [1,2,3]))))` ?

Comment: What python version are you running ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands requirement is not to use any string operations

Comment: `print(*[1,2,3], sep='')`

Comment: You should say in the question you can't use String operations... Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41068065/2308683

Comment: @YannVernier It returns `str`, that not what i want. please read the question properly

Comment: No it doesn't. It returns `None` after printing the numbers without separation. Printing fundamentally produces strings and there isn't a type named `integer`. What are you asking for?

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
print(int(''.join(str(e) for e in l)))
```

Comment: you are converting `int` to `str` and again to `int`. is there a way that directly from `int` array to `number` in python?

Comment: There isn't. `int` is an immutable object in python.

Comment: Even if it was mutable, what algorithm would you offer?
You can concatenate bytes, like `int.from_bytes([1, 2, 3], byteorder="big")`, but you will not get `123` because of binary concatenation